# Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined exception if js libraries loaded with status code 206

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring, electron

In my index.html I added 2 js files. One is library file, and second is my main.js file (which has angularjs codes).

```
<script src="js/lib/libraries.min.js?1599837573814"></script>
<script src="js/app/application.min.js?1599837573814"></script>
```

Sometime the library is loaded with 206 status code, then my website is broken and throws errors in Chrome console "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined exception".

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
spectrumLib.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at spectrumLib.js:1
```

If library file is loaded with 200 status code, it works as normal.
What is the 206 error code and how I fix this issue?